# Overtwisted contact structures on $S^3$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

All the isotopy classes of overtwisted contact structures are classified by the Hopf invariant. Are any of these contact structures contactomorphic?

Suppose $d_{3}(\xi_{n}) = n$, then my guess is that there could be a contactomorphism $\phi:(S^{3}, \xi_{n})\to (S^{3}, \xi_{-n})$, but I haven't been able to prove or find anything regarding this.